# How to view network requests logs in GKE?

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

How does one view request headers, payloads and response headers from an application thats deployed in GKE? For example if a node api invokes a function cleanData(); and it makes an api request to intuit API, how does one capture the network request/response headers in GCP logs?

I tried going to GCP console logs and its all just console.logs of the application and no network logs

Comment: GCP/GKE really has no visibility into calls made from your workloads.  The standard way to do this in Kubernetes (without changing your code) is typically to use a service mesh such as Istio or ASM and inject sidecars which will capture and log this info for you.